# Taking constant outside the summation

Tags: real-analysis, summation, real-numbers

In the below picture they have taken $a$ outside? Is it allowed? Is both terms involving summation are equal? [image]

**My attempt**

Term on left hand side is equal to $|\frac{1}{n}(a_1+... +a_n)-a|$

Whereas the term on right is equal to
$|\frac{1}{n}(a_1-a+a_2-a+... +a_n-a)|=|\frac{1}{n}(a_1+a_2+...+a_n-na)|$

**So how they are equal**?

Comment: It's because $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac an = a$

Comment: @CyclotomicField sir, how? As the summation is on $k$. So your provided summation is  $=\frac{a}{n}≠ \frac{a}{n} +...\text{(n times) }+\frac{a}{n}=a$

Comment: @GeneralMathematics $\sum_{k=1}^n \text{constant} = n \times \text{constant}$: you still add up $n$ terms, it's just that each of them don't change.

Comment: @kipf sir, so you mean we have treat constant as a variable? Because I think we apply summation on variable $k$ (here)

Comment: It's not added $k$ times, it's $n$ times because $k$ is the index of the variable but $n$ is constant. Convince yourself that $\sum_{k=1}^n 1 = n$ then multiply both sides by $\frac 1n$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField sir I have edited my previous comment

Comment: @CyclotomicField sir, it is really hard to convince myself that, that sum is $n$. Because,summation is on variable $k$ So how can we treat $1$ as a variable and add it repeatedly $n$ times to itself?

Comment: @GeneralMathematics $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ is $a_1 + \cdots + a_n$ by definition. So let $a_i = \frac{a}{n}$ for all $i = 1, \dots, n$. Then $a_1 + \cdots + a_n = \frac an + \cdots + \frac an = a$. The summation will involve $n$ terms; they just happen to not change.

Comment: @GeneralMathematics Note that $k$ is the variable but it's not involved in the sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k - a) &= \frac 1n\left(a_1 - a + a_2 - a + \cdots + a_n - a\right) \\
&= \frac 1n(a_1 + \cdots + a_n - na) \\
&= \frac 1n(a_1 + \cdots + a_n) - \frac 1n(na) \\
&= \frac 1n \left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right) - a.
\end{align*}